# Passing variables defined inside of one function into another

Tags: python, function, variables

#### Context:

I'm sure this has been asked elsewhere, but the topics I'm finding thus far are more advanced than what I'm doing and only confusing me further. I am a student in an intro to Python course, and am working on a "Lottery Number" assignment. Basically, randomly generate a 7-digit lottery number and print it back out.

That much I get, but I am trying to approach this from a less literal perspective and a more practical one. As in, I want the user to define how many numbers they need and which numbers to choose from. From there, I want the program to generate random numbers that fit the criteria they set.

My instructor wants everything done inside of functions, so I am trying to attempt the following:

#### What I'm doing:

- `main()` Function - everything inside of here.
- `get_info()` to collect the data from the user, number of digits (`MaxDigits`), range minimum (`MinChoice`), range maximum (`MaxChoice`).
- `lottery_pick()` take the variables and do the lottery thing with them.

I have it "working", but I can only do so if I have `lottery_pick(`) function run inside of the `get_info()` function. I imagine there has to be a way to define these variables independently, and just pass the variables from `get_info()` to `lottery_pick()`.

```
import random

# Define the main function
def main():
    get_info()
    exit_prompt()

def get_info():
    # Set Variables to 0
    MaxDigits = 0

    # Let the user know what we are doing
    print("Let's choose your lottery numbers!")
    print("First, How many numbers do you need for this lottery?")

    # Request the user input the number of lottery numbers we need
    while True:
        try:
            MaxDigits = int(input('Please enter how many numbers you need to choose: '))
            if MaxDigits > 0:
                break;
            else:
                print('Please enter an integer for how many numbers are being drawn. ')
        except:
            continue
    print('Next, we need to know the smallest and largest numbers allowed to choose from')

    # Request user input smallest number in range of numbers to pick from.
    while True:
        try:
            MinChoice = int(input('Please enter the lowest number you are allowed to choose from: '))
            if MinChoice >= 0:
                break;
            else: print ('Please enter an integer, 0 or greater for the smallest number to pick from.')
        except:
            continue
    # Request user input largest number in range of numbers to pick from.
    while True:
        try:
            MaxChoice = int(input('Please enter the largest number you are allowed to choose from: '))
            if MaxChoice >= 0:
                break;
            else: print ('Please enter an integer, 0 or greater for the greatest number to pick from.')
        except:
            continue

    # Define the function to actually assemble the lottery number
    def lottery_pick(lot_digits, lot_min, lot_max):
        numbers = [0] * lot_digits
        for index in range(lot_digits):
            numbers[index] = random.randint (lot_min, lot_max)
        print('Here are your lottery numbers!:')
        print(numbers)

    # Execute the function - I've not yet figured out how to pass the variables from the get_info
    # function to the lottery_pick function without lottery_pick being inside of get_info.
    lottery_pick(MaxDigits, MinChoice, MaxChoice)

def exit_prompt():
    while True:
        try:

# use lower method to convert all strings input to lower-case. This method
# allows user to input their answer in any case or combination of cases.
            ExitPrompt = str.lower(input('Would you like to generate another lottery number? Please enter "yes" or "no" '))
            if ExitPrompt == 'yes':
                 main()
            elif ExitPrompt =='no':
                print('Goodbye!')
                exit()

# If an answer other than yes or no is input, prompt the user again to choose to re-run or to exit
# until an acceptable answer is provided.
            else:
                print('Please enter "yes" to generate another lottery number, or "no" to exit. ')
        except:
            continue
main()
```

Comment: There is no problem just moving the `lottery_pick()` function to just below the `get_info()` function instead of it being inside. There are other problems with your code, but that is not one of them.

Comment: While it's possible to use global variables to pass data from one function to another it has long been considered a poor programming practice — in other words, explicitly passing the data from one function to another is the better way to do it. Another excellent approach for avoiding them is to define classes to encapsulate code and data.